# Network request failed when release build

Tags: android, react-native, build, react-redux, native

When i run `react-native run-android` , it will working proper

Then i needs apk

I run `react-native run-android --variant=release`

Then while i run apk showing `Network request failed`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" .....` in file `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`